# Automating cleaning old page versions?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there a way to clean out old versions of a page? Would be great to either set in the configs or automate keeping only the last X number of revisions to a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe does have an algorithm by which old versions age off. The further back in time the fewer versions are kept, however Apostrophe tries to preserve transitions between authors.

A task to drop all past versions of a doc or all docs is straightforward to write (see the `aposDocVersions` collection) but it's not something we've added so far.